# Let computed property listen to other objectcontrollers

Tags: ember.js

I have the following router:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('cart', function() {
        // order routes
        this.route('shipping');
        this.route('checkout');
        this.route('payment'); 
        this.route('thanks');

    });
});
```

On route `Cart` I have a `cartTotal` computed property. I want to have it update when a variable in route `shipping` changes.

My computed property in the `cart` controller:

```
needs: ['cartShipping'],

cartitemsTotal: function() {
    // logic
    return totalCosts;
}.property('model.@each.price', 'controllers.cartShipping.shippingMethod'),
```

However this gives an error: `Error while processing route: cart <app@controller:cart::ember404> needs [ controller:cartShipping ] but it could not be found Error: <app@controller:cart::ember404> needs [ controller:cartShipping ] but it could not be found`

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `needs` property on child controllers, only parent controllers. You want to use the `cart.shipping` controller, but what if your user is at the `cart.checkout` route? In that case, the `cart.shipping` controller won't be active (and might not even exist if the container hasn't instantiated it yet).

For almost everything in Ember.js, you can reach up the hierarchy but you can almost never reach down. This is one of those cases. You probably need to restructure your routes to do what you want.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the insight! Now I do toggle a property from a 'sub-controller' to fire the recalculation on a `resource` route item.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not stating the obvious, have you defined "cartShipping"?

I have found that the controllers need to be define in order to pull properties such as `shippingMethod`

```
App.CartShippingController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    shippingMethod: 'method-here'
});
```

Comment: If the controller isn't explicitly defined Ember will create one for you. If won't create the property for you, so you'll get back `undefined`, but you won't get an error. I'm not sure if that applies to the `needs` functionality, but it doesn't really matter since, as I said, you can only reach up the route hierarchy. Ember will generate the controller before you need it.

Comment: @GJK was the answer, I now toggle in the 'sub-controller' a property of the `resource` route item. It Works!